# Calling a React component within itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is more of a theoretical question and we use states for such cases but let's say: since every React component is a function, why nothing happens when we call it within itself like the example below. Shouldn't calling the function cause the component to render itself again?

```
const CallComp = () => {
  let title = "Not clicked yet.";
  const clickHandler = () => {
    title = "Clicked!";
    CallComp();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Test</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default CallComp;
```

Comment: No. There is no code in the function that renders anything. When react renders a function component, it does a) set up hooks to work b) call the function c) render the JSX elements it returned. If you had used any hooks in your example, you would in fact have gotten an exception.

Comment: This isn’t a react question. Calling a (recursive) function from within itself doesn’t cause the original function call to execute again/behave diferently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A render function doesn't usually have side effects; in particular, it doesn't have the side effect of actually mounting the component on the page. Rather, the render function is called by React, and it returns information to React to tell it what to display. If the render function is called other than by React, well, that has no effect, unless its caller decides to do something with whatever the render function returns.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call a react function in itself because it is breaking the rules of react hooks

if you want to rerender a component then use useState();

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from "react" // import useState

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CallComp/>
  );
}
const CallComp = () => {
  // let title = "Not clicked yet."; this does not cause a re-render
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Not clicked yet."); // so you need to use useState if you want to re-render
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle("Clicked!")
    // CallComp(); this line breaks the rules of react hooks
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Test</button>
    </>
  );
};
```